# Why is the page split into two?

Tags: html, css

I'm just combining css files from other templates but I can figure out why I'm getting a split in the pages. Please take a look here, might need to widen it up to see the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/8xz8m/

It is hard to describe but when I re-size the browser I'm getting a very weird effect. Like two windows moving apart. Does anyone have any guidance I can follow to fix the problem?

[Screenshot:

[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2onor.png)

Comment: Please attach a screenshot. I don't know what you're seeing. At least mention which browser you're using to produce this "weird effect".

Comment: I'm using opera. Try re-sizing only horizontally. When the upload bar goes to the middle a while line cuts off half of it. Here is an image http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/2249/60510508.png

Comment: I see what you mean, but I closed your page before investigating. You have some script on the page that is running constantly, using a lot of CPU, and eating memory.

Comment: On the webpage or on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`overflow:hidden` is the main culprit. Remove it, and everything "magically" shows up again.